# Unable to find headers in static library

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, cocoapods, dtcoretext

I'd like to add DTCoreText to my project. I followed the instructions (starting at the [DTCoreTExt GitHub page](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText)) to setup the project using CocoaPods. Finally I've created a "libPod.a" library file.

I've added the library file to my project (by copying the file in to a project sub-folder and added the file to the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries".

Finally I've tried to run the "[Smoke test](https://docs.cocoanetics.com/DTCoreText/docs/Programming%20Guide.html)" as defined in the "DTCoreText Programming Guide".

Without success. XCode can't find the DTCoreText.h file (or any other file of this lib).

Have I missed something? Please help! :o)

Comment: you've added the .a file to your own project, but have you added the .h files into your project anywhere?

Comment: No, I just copied the .a file. Do I really need to add all .h files of the DTCoreText project?

Comment: Thank you @Michael, this was the right hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the `Header Search Paths` in the Build Settings to ensure the path is correct?

Comment: Hmm. Yes, I tried to pull in the folder holding the lib file by using `$(PROJECT_DIR)/libraries` but without success.

Comment: If the path is correct, then the other thing to check it so ensure that the header file was added when the Lib was created, copying the .h files to "Resources" in the build phases of the Target

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Michael and @eharo2, you pointed into the right direction.

I wasn't aware that it's necessary to copy ALL header files together with the library file.

Btw. the relevant path is defined in the *Build Settings* under *Search Paths* in `Library Search Paths`